# How to store image from picturebox to database, in sql server 2008 using c# (VS 2010)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

im new to c#, can somone please tell me how to add image to database, from picture box using c#.
i have a registration form which user is added to database(SQL 2008), but i have no idea how to add image of the user to database, which contain many columns of user information and a column of picture.
`sql<2008> visual studio <2010>`

Comment: Read the image after upload, and make a binary string and then you can set this string in the database column.

Comment: this is definetely a clone, it was asked so much, that i really do not want to search for colneables, it is soo boring. why you did not read the FAQ about using this site?

Comment: to admins: you definetely might add the phrase "i have no idea how to add image of the user to database" to blacklisted phrases list, really

Answer (score 1):

You should have a binary field in DB for that. Read your [image like binary array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350679/convert-a-bitmap-into-a-byte-array-in-c) and save in into DB. But It is not goog practice as for me. I usually save image in cloud or folder and in DB - only URL

Answer (score 0):

create table IMAGELOAD
(img1 binary)

while saving send path of the file to this field

Suggestion :
Instead saving image into database.Save in application folder.

Answer (score 0):

Can you be more specific? 
What you don't know how to do?
How to get image from pictureBox? This can help you, hope.

```
//Save content of imageBytes to db VARBINARY(MAX) 
byte[] imageBytes;
using (imgStr = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
{
    pictureBox.Image.Save(imgStr, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg); // Depending on your format.
    imageBytes = imgStr.ToArray();
}

//to load from db use
using (Stream imgStr = new MemoryStream(imageBytes))
{
    pictureBox.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(imgStr);
}
```