# Convert image to ushort?[]

Tags: c#

I want to convert bitmap image to ushort?[] type. 
I am following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350679/convert-a-bitmap-into-a-byte-array) but it does not serve the purpose as I dont require byte array.

Please help.

**Solution**

```
var shorts = Array.ConvertAll(croppedImageByteArray, b => (ushort?)b);
```

Comment: What do you want in the shorts - a 16-bit representation of the colour in each cell, or the byte representation of the image in some format (BMP, PNG, JPG) extended to shorts? And why nullable?

Comment: Actually I will hit one WSDL webservice, which requires me to send image  in this form.

Comment: 16 bit is high color mode.  If you an application requires 16 bit you have to convert the 8 bit images before send to 16 bit format.  You can't just cast a 8 bit image to 16 bit.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the same link and cast the bytes to ushort? 
On the final result where you have the byte array you can do

```
var WhatIWant = TheByteArray.Cast<ushort?>();
```

It's only useful if you specifically need that type, if you want to convert up from byte to a larger type to get more information that's a no go as that information doesn't exist to begin with if it's stored as bytes from the start.

If this doesn't help explain clearly what you are trying to do and most of all why so we can better help.

Comment: It does not convert byte array to ushort?[].

Comment: @BeelalAhmed It does, it's exactly what it does, but i doubt it is what you want which is why i said explain clearly WHY you want to do that

Comment: I see you added the answer to that as a comment on the original post, in that case yes it will work (it will be a ushort array) but i doubt that the service just wants any ushort array, refer to their documentation but i doubt they just want the bitmap casted to ushorts

Comment: AFAICS this will generate an enumerable of ushorts (not nullable ushorts), but that can probably be fixed with a Select and a ToArray.

Comment: I didn't see he wanted them nullable, it doesn't require a select, can just fix the cast signature, doing it now

Comment: This converts to `ushort[]`, the question (inexplicably) calls for `ushort?[]`.

Comment: I am getting compile time error of non conversion. Cannot implicitly convert type from IEnumerable<ushort?> to ushort?[]

Comment: croppedImageByteArray.Cast<ushort?>().ToArray() is givnig error. 'An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in System.Core.dll'

Comment: I solved it with it. var shorts = Array.ConvertAll(croppedImageByteArray, b => (ushort?)b);

Comment: The compile time error just Required a ToArray since you want an array