# Android Xamarin - retrieve the image stored in an imageview

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android, visual-studio-2017

I retrieve an image as a byte arrary stored in a database convert it to a bitmap and display it in an Imageview.  I want to be able to retrieve that image from the Imageview and store it back to the database.  My database retrieval code is:

```
TheService myService = new TheService.DataInterface();
DataSet MyPhoto = myService.GetPhoto(id);
byte[] imageBytes = (byte[])MyPhoto.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
imageview.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

At some point the image is changed and I need to store it back in the database.  How would I get the image out of the imageview?  Everything I've seen thus far deals with an attached drawable, there is no drawable in this case.

There doesn't seem to be a method like:

```
Bitmap photo = imageview.GetCurrentImage();
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

**** UPDATED ****

Once I get the image I need to convert it into a byte array to save it into the database.  I've tried several different methods with no success, the latest is:

```
using Java.Nio;
public static byte[] ImageToByte(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    var bytes = new Byte[30000];
    try
    {
        var byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.Allocate(bitmap.ByteCount);
        bitmap.CopyPixelsToBuffer(byteBuffer);
        bytes = byteBuffer.ToArray<byte>();
        return bytes;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        var message = ex.Message;
        return bytes;
    }
}
```

This generates an exception "Unable to cast from 'java/nio/HeapByteBuffer' to '[B'"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is something like below:

```
   BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = ((BitmapDrawable) imageView.Drawable);
    Bitmap bitmap;
    if(bitmapDrawable==null){
        imageView.BuildDrawingCache();
        bitmap = imageView.GetDrawingCache();
        imageView.BuildDrawingCache(false);
    }else
    {
        bitmap = bitmapDrawable .Bitmap;
    }
```

Where imageView is the imageView control from which you want your bitmap

Update:

Convert from bitmap to byteArray something like this:

```
   byte[] bitmapData;
   using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
   { 
  bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Png, 0, stream);
    bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
   }
```

Comment: That (apparently worked, not sure yet because now I need to convert the image into a byte array so I can store it into the database.  I modified my question.

Comment: I have added an update for you, and just so you know if you have a requirement where you need to do multiple things you should mention it in your question, changing the question once it is answered is not how StackOverflow works ask everything you want in one shot anyway goodluck.

Comment: Thanks, that all compiled and I'll begin end to end testing now.  I'll post the results once I'm done with that.

Yes, I should have posted both requirements, I had assumed that I could write the bytearray code myself.  I assumed wrong ....

Comment: End to End tests were successfull. Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Its my pleasure to help, in case if you are learning xamarin and if you want to learn it further you can follow me on medium, and checkout my blogs! I blog every week something or the other and how to do it in xamarin. Link in my Bio, Happy coding!