# Error: when Image data converting to pdf from DataGridView table which is filtered from database

Tags: c#, datagridview, itext

I'm trying to convert DataGridView data with an image column which is filtered from my SQL database into a PDF file in C#. I wrote this code using iTextSharp, but I get an error

> Unable to cast object of type System.Drawing.bitmap to type system byte[]

Can anyone kindly help me out?

Thanks.

Here is my code:

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)  
{  
    if(row.Cells[0].Value!= null)  
    {  
        pdfTable.AddCell(row.Cells[0].Value.ToString());  
    }  

    if (row.Cells[1].Value != null)  
    {  
        byte[] img = (byte[])row.Cells[1].Value;  
        pdfTable.AddCell(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(img));  
   }  
}
```

Comment: What the message implies is that you need to convert the bitmap to bite array before atempting a conversion, besides you are using iTextSharp.text to get the image maybe it isn't right

Comment: then what should i do for converting my datagridview bitmap image into byte array? any resource pls?

Comment: In which line is the error happening I think is happening here byte[] img = (byte[])row.Cells[1].Value; would you please confirm that?

Comment: yes, you are right.. actually by default- datagridview contain bitmap image when image data called from database.. then i trying to convert this image column data as a pdf, its unable to cast bitmap to byte.. search over internet, but didnt get exact solution yet :(

Comment: I added an answer to your problem. if it helps dont forget to accept and arrow up the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is produced due to a failed casting. According to this [Convert a bitmap into a byte array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350679/convert-a-bitmap-into-a-byte-array) you might need to add a method to perform the conversion.

```
private byte[] ImageToByte(Image img)
{
    ImageConverter converter = new ImageConverter();
    return (byte[])converter.ConvertTo(img, typeof(byte[]));
}
```

So you code might look something like this instead.

```
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)  
{  
    //... extra code
    if (row.Cells[1].Value != null)  
    {  
        byte[] img = ImageToByte(row.Cells[1].Value);  
        pdfTable.AddCell(iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(img));  
   }  
}
```

Hope this helps