# How to convert a System.Drawing.Bitmap to a UnityEngine.Texture?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
Texture2D tex = new Texture2D(200, 300, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
Rectangle screenSize = System.Windows.Forms.Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;

Bitmap target = new Bitmap(screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height);
using (System.Drawing.Graphics g = System.Drawing.Graphics.FromImage(target))
{
    g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, new Size(screenSize.Width, screenSize.Height));
}

m_Renderer.enabled = true;

m_Renderer.material.SetTexture("_MainTex", target);
```

I'm trying to set a bitmap as a texture in Unity, but I get the error

> cannot convert from 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to 'UnityEngine.Texture'

Any ideas how I can convert the bitmap to a texture?

Answer (score 0):

You could try converting Bitmap to byte[] (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350679/convert-a-bitmap-into-a-byte-array)). After that you can call [Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData(byte[])](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.LoadRawTextureData.html) or [Texture2D.LoadImage(byte[])](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/ImageConversion.LoadImage.html).