# Saving Image to disk using Screenshot.Net library

Tags: c#, wpf, screenshot

hope everyone is doing well.

I am using the [Screenshot.Net library](https://github.com/gilyes/Screenshot.NET) to take an area drawn screenshots of a screen from a WPF application. The problem I am having is saving the screenshot to a directory within the project folder.

This is how the library currently saves the Image however it is not being stored to any directory:

```
public static BitmapSource ToBitmapSource(this Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            bitmap.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Png);
            var bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
            bitmapImage.BeginInit();
            bitmapImage.StreamSource = new MemoryStream(stream.ToArray());
            bitmapImage.EndInit();
            bitmapImage.Freeze();

            return bitmapImage;
        }
    }
```

I have tried specifying a directory save path but have so far been unable to get it to work. Any advice on how to proceed would be appreciated.

Comment: well - you're writing it to a memorystream.. have you tried writing it to a filestream instead?

Comment: I haven't tried that yet but let me give it a shot now. Apologies if this was a silly post still fairly new to the .net framework.

Comment: You already have the bitmap in a MemoryStream, Just call `File.WriteAllBytes(path, stream.ToArray());`

Comment: @Clemens when I tired that I got an error message saying cannot implicitly convert void to System.Io.Stream.

Comment: See the accepted answer. It's there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, get a `byte[]` from the MemoryStream

```
stream.Position = 0;
byte[] imgBytes = stream.ToArray();
```

Then, use built-in libs for writing.

```
string basePath="<Your path without File name>";
string fileName="<Your image name with extension>";
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(Path.Combine(basePath, fileName), imgBytes);
```

Comment: @StormRhoda have you refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350679/convert-a-bitmap-into-a-byte-array

Comment: Thanks, @Udhayarajan this worked.