# How to print an image with a thermal printer

Tags: c#, printing, xamarin.android

I've been following many SO answers and none of them work. This is one of them, and I think is the most promising ([the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350679/convert-a-bitmap-into-a-byte-array))

```cs
        public static async Task PrintImageFilesAsync(BluetoothSocket _socket, IEnumerable<FileResult> imageFiles)
        { 
            foreach(var file in imageFiles) {
                var path = file.FullPath;
                var imageFile = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
                
                Bitmap originalImage = await BitmapFactory.DecodeStreamAsync(imageFile);
                var strippedImage = StripColor(originalImage); // Strips the image of ALL colour, and re-colourizes it all to black.

                using (var memStream = new MemoryStream()) {
                    int bufferLength = (int)imageFile.Length;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLength];

                    await strippedImage.CompressAsync(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 0, memStream); // Writes image data to memStream
                    buffer = memStream.ToArray(); // Writes data in memStream to buffer
                    await imageFile.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, bufferLength); // Modifies the buffer IN PLACE
                    try
                    {
                        await _socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, bufferLength); // This part is responsible for printing.
                    }
                    catch (Java.IO.IOException ioEx)
                    {
                        originalImage.Dispose();
                        strippedImage.Dispose();

                        memStream.Close();
                        memStream.Dispose();

                        _socket.Close();
                        _socket.Dispose();

                        CrossToastPopUp.Current.ShowToastError($"{ioEx.Message}\nError: {ioEx}");
                        return;
                    }
                    strippedImage.Dispose();
                    originalImage.Dispose();
                }
                var status = "Print job completed.";
                Debug.WriteLine(status);
                CrossToastPopUp.Current.ShowToastMessage(status);
            }
            _socket.Close();
            _socket.Dispose();
        }
```

The function then strips the image of all color with `StripColor`

```cs
        private static Task<Bitmap> StripColor(Bitmap image)
        {
            image = image.Copy(Bitmap.Config.Argb8888, true);
            try
            {
                image.EraseColor(0);
            }
            catch (Java.Lang.IllegalStateException isEx)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"ERROR:\n\n{isEx.Message}");
                return null;
            }

            return image;
        }
```

With the current code this is the output when I print an image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hZjHr.jpg
It just prints out random gibberish. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: I think the problem is with `buffer = memStream.ToArray();`, at no point in your code are you writing anything to `memStream`. Judging from the linked SO answer, you should probably add `image.Save(memStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);` before `buffer = memStream.ToArray();`

Comment: But in general: It's incredibly complicated to understand what your code is doing! You have `image` and `_image`, as well as a buffer floating around, and it's being passed as a parameter which is unnecessary, so, in general, I think your code could use some cleanup

Comment: I think you need more information about the printer itself. Does the printer support printing images? And if yes, in which format? Due to the fact, that you send raw binary data through a serial interface you have to take care, what the printer expects to get.

Comment: "in general, I think your code could use some cleanup"
I know, I usually do that after it works.

Comment: @Oliver "Does the printer support printing images?" Yes. "And if yes, in which format?" I have no idea.

Comment: @MindSwipe "I think the problem is with `buffer = memStream.ToArray();`, at no point in your code are you writing anything to memStream" I updated the question, and replaced `file` with `memStream` in `PrintImage`. The result is still the same.

Comment: The entire code as it is right now is a mess (no offence), and a lot of it is redundant, as what's actually happening is this `var file = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);` then `var buffer = new byte[(int)file.Length];` then `await file.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);` and finally `await _socket.OutputStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);`. It's incredibly hard to see what's going on, which is why I'm an advocate for "clean as you go". And as you can now clearly see, you're just sending raw bytes from the file to the printer, and none of your other code is ran

Comment: "The entire code as it is right now is a mess (no offence)" I know its a mess. I can print text when I send bytes to the printer. I'm just assuming that I can do the same with images. "...and none of your other code is ran" I don't really see this though.

Comment: @MindSwipe I cleaned up the code as per your suggestion

Comment: @DexYap any update? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @devs121 yes, use this [api](https://github.com/lukevp/ESC-POS-.NET)

Comment: @DexYap this seems that will solve the problem. I tried it, but I couldn't connect a bluetooth printer. Did you connect in this way? I mean, in example of the api shows `var printer = new SerialPrinter(portName: "COM5", baudRate: 115200);`, but for bluetooth how can I show the Address of it? Can you help me? Thanks for now.

Comment: I connected it through classes available on the Android.Bluetooth namespace

Comment: @DexYap Cool, but when it goes to `printer.Write()` it is referenced by the connection that you do with the printer (my answer above). How can you reference the printer connection by Android.Bluetooth to this `printer.Write()`? (Sorry for so many questions, i'm struggling with it about 5 months to find some solution).

Comment: And one more thing: I'm using an Android cellphone to send print to my printer (it's a thermal printer) by Bluetooth. I'm not using any USB cable. Does it work with it that I'm using, right?

Comment: Create a new question. It's more appropriate. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/YJH16120/TSC_MobileApp/blob/master/MobileApp/Printing/Printing.cs#L56) and [this](https://github.com/YJH16120/TSC_MobileApp/blob/master/MobileApp/Printing/Printing.cs#L150). And keep note of the imports.

Comment: @DexYap I'm printing now, but I have a big problem about the height of what I'm printing. I created a question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67288683/print-image-esc-pos), please take a look. Thanks for now.