# How do i retrieve the thumbnail image of a video from mysql database and display it on web application

Tags: c#, asp.net

Please help... I am stuck at this for 2 weeks. Thank you.

Having these codes

```
public static Bitmap GetThumbnail(string video, string thumbnail)
        {
            var cmd = "ffmpeg  -itsoffset -1  -i " + '"' + video + '"' + " -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -s 320x240 " + '"' + thumbnail + '"';

            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
                FileName = "cmd.exe",
                Arguments = "/C " + cmd
            };

            var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = startInfo
            };

            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit(5000);

            return LoadImage(thumbnail);
        }

        static Bitmap LoadImage(string path)
        {
            var ms = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(path));
            return (Bitmap)Image.FromStream(ms);    
        }
```

How do I retrieve and display the thumbnail in aspx file?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that your code is working and get the Bitmap... in this case you create a handler lets names it `image.ashx`.

You put inside your handler this code

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    // assume its jpeg
    context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

    // here I call your "working" code
    var cImageToRender = GetThumbnail("VideoName", "thumbnail");

    // convert it for the stream
    var imgData = BitmapToByteArray(cImageToRender);
   
    // send it to the browser
    context.Response.OutputStream.Write(imgData, 0, imgData.Length);    
}

// this function reference
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/17244814/159270
public static byte[] BitmapToByteArray(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    BitmapData bmpdata = null;

    try
    {
        bmpdata = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, bitmap.PixelFormat);
        int numbytes = bmpdata.Stride * bitmap.Height;
        byte[] bytedata = new byte[numbytes];
        IntPtr ptr = bmpdata.Scan0;

        Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytedata, 0, numbytes);

        return bytedata;
    }
    finally
    {
        if (bmpdata != null)
            bitmap.UnlockBits(bmpdata);
    }
}
```

and inside your `.aspx` (or any html) page you get the image as

```
<img src="image.ashx">
```

This is in general the steps to follow - small details maybe need to be fixed in the final code.