"strReadFile.BaseStream.ReadTimeout" occurred when I converted a BMP image into a data stream
In this project, I converted the content on the panel into a picture in BMP format, and then converted the picture into a data stream and printed it from the printer, but the picture was never printed.
I also tested the string and this was printed successfully. But when I was debugging, I found that some code appeared

'strReadFile.BaseStream.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Below is my code:
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(panel1.Width, panel1.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);
        panel1.DrawToBitmap(bmp, new Rectangle(0, 0, panel1.Width, panel1.Height));
        bmp.Save("led.bmp", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

        paint();

        File.Delete("led.bmp");
    }

    private libUsbContorl.UsbOperation NewUsb = new libUsbContorl.UsbOperation();

    private void paint()
    {
        NewUsb.FindUSBPrinter();
        for (int i = 0; i < NewUsb.USBPortCount; i++)
        {
            if (NewUsb.LinkUSB(i))
            {
                SendData2USB("SIZE 58 mm,60 mm\r\n");//标签尺寸
                SendData2USB("GAP 0 mm,0 mm\r\n");//间距为0
                SendData2USB("CLS\r\n");//清空缓冲区
                SendData2USB("DENSITY 7\r\n");//打印浓度
                SendData2USB("REFERENCE 0,0\r\n");
                SendData2USB("TEXT 15,10,\"1\",0,1,1,\"asdfggDDD\"\r\n");
                SendData2USB("TEXT 15,60,\"TSS24.BF2\",0,1,1,\"简体字\"\r\n");

                StreamReader strReadFile = new StreamReader(@"./led.bmp");
                byte[] byteReadData = new byte[strReadFile.BaseStream.Length];
                strReadFile.BaseStream.Read(byteReadData, 0, byteReadData.Length);
                strReadFile.Close();
                SendData2USB("DOWNLOAD \"led.bmp\",4094,");
                SendData2USB(byteReadData);//bmp数据
                SendData2USB("PUTBMP 14,110,\"led.bmp\"\r\n");
                SendData2USB("PRINT 1\r\n");

                NewUsb.CloseUSBPort();
            }
        }
    }

    private void SendData2USB(byte[] str)
    {
        NewUsb.SendData2USB(str, str.Length);
    }
    private void SendData2USB(string str)
    {
        byte[] by_SendData = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(54936).GetBytes(str);
        SendData2USB(by_SendData);
    }

How can I solve this problem?  Please help me.

IMHO, skip the file and use a stream eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350679/convert-a-bitmap-into-a-byte-array. No idea what printing protocol you are trying to use there though.

@JeremyLakeman Thanks for your help, I tried the link you provided and it's great post. But the label printer still didn't print out the image. But thank you very much, at least I have ruled out that this problem is not caused by the data stream read timeout. I'm wondering if the resulting image is too large, and I'm looking for a way to modify the pixels without losing other content. I don’t know about the printing protocol. I am making printing software based on the demo provided by the manufacturer.
